# Trouble with wp_reset_postdata() in Admin Panel

Tags: wp-query, admin, wp-reset-postdata

I'm hooking into 'edit_form_after_editor'

```
add_action('edit_form_after_editor', 'make_the_button_to_generate_a_report_number');
function make_the_button_to_generate_a_report_number($post) {
```

Check that I am dealing with a custom post type of 'publications'

```
if ($post->post_type != 'publications') return;
```

Create a number of arguments that I then run in a WP_Query

```
$new_query = new WP_Query($report_number_args);
```

use that data to do stuff...
Then I want to reset `$post` back to how it was, so I run

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

But `$post` stays on the last item I had received from my new WP_Query().

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a special way to reset the postdata when dealing with a custom post type?

**Update**:
At the beginning and end of the function I have:

```
echo("<h4>the title = </h4>");
echo(the_title());
```

At the beginning the title is the title for the custom post type I clicked on to edit, or blank if I am creating a new post.
At the end the title is always the last post from my query.

Comment: Where are you calling `wp_reset_postdata()` in relation to the rest of the loop?

Comment: I believe so, I call it right at the end of my function, outside of any loop that works with the $new_query data.  Is there something I should look for to know it's being called in relation to the rest of the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the official stance is to not use `WP_Query` in the admin panel. There'a a [trac ticket #18408](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18408) on this exact same issue. Here's what Boone says:

> The root issue is that `wp_reset_postdata()` is designed to reset globals to match the main query. But in the case of `post.php`, there is no main query - the `$post` global is populated manually, using `get_post()`, rather than through the normal `$wp_query` loop.

Because the post is populated manually in the admin panel you will not be able to reset it in a traditional fashion. If you print out the `global $wp_query` at this point you'll also find that it's empty.

The preferred method is to instead use `get_posts()` which doesn't override the `global $post` object.

---

You could manually preserve the `global $post` object in a custom variable and manually reset it once you're done with your loop. That being said, I do not know the overarching consequences with this method. It's safer to use `get_posts()` when possible.

```
global $post;

$tmp_post = $post;
$posts_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $posts_query->have_posts() ) {
    
    while( $posts_query->have_posts() ) {
        $posts_query->the_post();
        the_title();
    }
    
    $post = $tmp_post;
}
```

---

Another solution may be, specifically in the admin panel, store the `global $post` in the `global $wp_query` object during `loop_start`. For example:

```
/**
 * Store the global $post object so we may reset it
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function wpse377565_admin_post_storage() {
    
    global $wp_query,
        $post;
    
    if( ! is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }
    
    $wp_query->post = $post;
    
}
add_action( 'loop_start', 'wpse377565_admin_post_storage' );
```

The `wp_reset_postdata()` function looks for `$this->post` in the global $wp_query object which is both empty and available in admin requests. We could use the above action hook to allow us to call `wp_reset_postdata()`. Again, I also do not know the overarching consequences of doing this, use with caution.